# How to match a date path in Backbone router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CEpPA/6/)I have a Backbone application where I wish to trigger methods on the router with links like these

```
<a href="/2015/09/28/do-you-drink-whiskey">link</a>
<a href="/2015/09/29/do-you-drink-beer/">link</a>
```

Using this code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/"]', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
 Backbone.history.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
}
```

I try to capture any click on a link that begins with `/`, which my two links do. By passing the `trigger: true` option, I understand that I am triggering a route on the router.

In the router, I try to match anything that begins with `2015` (as I understand there is no need to put the initial `/`)

```
var R = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "": "list",
        "restaurants/:id": "restoDetails",
        "2015/*": "matchAnything"
    },
    matchAnything: function(){
        alert("yeah, match")
    },
    restoDetails: function() {
        console.log('restoDetails', arguments);
    },
    list: function() {
        console.log('list', arguments);
    }
});
new R;
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true);
```

The matchAnything method is not getting called when I click the link. Question: How can I use the router to match a link that begins with a date (like I have done with my links)?

Update, my version was based on [this code](https://github.com/bouzuya/backbone-pushstate-example/blob/master/public/scripts/main.js) and, in the README.md of that github repo, there is a link to a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to listen to all hrefs and determine if the link is local or not, since links that begin with `/` can also be remote links with https/http excluded (lots of examples on SO for checking if a link is local or not).

It would be nice if you made a Fiddle without runtime errors ;) But anyway here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/0hLn0smc/

You needed to name the part after `/2015/`, this is sometimes called a "splat" but you could write any word there:

```
"2015/*splat": "matchAnything"
```

Comment: Thank you. If you can clarify one thing...I thought `*` matched any number of any characters. Why do I need to write a word (whether it be `splat` or `blah`) after `*`? I don't see any documentation about that in this regular expression guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions . Sorry about the jsfiddle...I have trouble getting them to work with console statements.